# GPIO contol: FCEUX NES game with keyboard emulation

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, keyboard, emulation

I am working on a project to build a small gamepad wired to a raspberry pi's GPIO ports. The gamepad is working - a python program emulates keyboard input using the uinput module when buttons on the pad are pressed, and on any interface other than the fceux emulator game window - where it is unresponsive - it posts the keyboard output.

I was wondering if there is anything about this emulator which would stop it recieving simulated keyboard input, when all other programs seem to (browsers, terminal, filemanager etc)

I'm running raspbian os and using python 2.6.

If you need any more info then just say :)